# "change picture" pop-up link issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, profile-picture

There are 2 things related to "change picture" pop-up link in SE profile which look like bugs (at least for QA specialist):

- Link pops up even when mouse pointer is above the marked region: I'd would think that it should just have the "change" link visible only when the pointer is above my userpic:

[image: extra pop-up area for change pic link]

- Hardly ever visible, but still: 1px height line still uncovered by popup:

[image: uncovered pic line under pop-up]

QA at your service.

Comment: Just in case - I use FF 18.0.1 (latest stable), running on Win7 Ultimate x64 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hover in rep / badges was intentional as it helps users discover the change picture feature.  I have fixed the 2px that was not aligned properly.  Look for this in the next build.

Comment: Thanks, will tick (i.e. validate) as soon as fix is in place!

Comment: Fix in place, passed QA) thanks!